# Does migrating to CfEnv in Spring Boot make properties file redundant?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, cloud-foundry

The deprecation of Auto Reconfiguration in new JavaBuildPack is puzzling me.

see https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/java/configuring-service-connections.html#migrating

The solution is to create a bean `CfEnv` and to use `SpEL` to set the properties, e.g.:

```
cassandra.contact-points=#{ cfEnv.findCredentialsByTag('cassandra').get('node_ips') }
```

But it seems that the expression language doesn't work with YAML properties. I'm not even sure the `.properties` will work either. Even if this works with YAML/Properties file then there are scenarios that we will be in trouble, for example, when we don't have environment specific property file but instead we have component specific properties:

We have this structure in one of our repositories:

```
#application-component1.yml
  myprop.one: ${vcap.services.myservice.myprop.one}
#application-vcap.yml
  vcap.services.myservice.myprop.one: default-value-when-run-locally
```

Now if we use `@Value("#{cfEnv.getService('service').username}")` then how can we set the property in YAML or `.properties` file? How do we run this in our local server when developers are testing it?

Another question is, what if we decide to switch to say Kubernetes or non-cloud option; doesn't that mean we should remove all `CfEnv` entries?

I can't find anything that addresses these issues, I hope someone can shed light on this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `${vcap.services.myservice.myprop.one}`, which appears to be the case from your example, you can continue using that. The `vcap.*` prefix is [provided by Spring Boot itself](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/cloud/CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor.java). The `cloud.` prefix was provided by Spring Auto Reconfiguration and it's **ONLY** the `cloud.*` prefix that is going away.

> The Spring Auto Reconfiguration module would expose a set of property placeholder values that one could use to access values from `VCAP_SERVICES`. If you are using these place holders, then you need to switch from using `cloud.<property>` to `vcap.<property>`.
>
> Spring Boot exposes the same information, just under the `vcap.` prefix instead of `cloud.`.